Simulate an Audio Device in a Docker Container
I'm trying to run the latest version of Stardew Valley in a Docker container to run it as a server setup (for the record, I own the game and am using my own purchased copy to do this, per this repository's instructions).
When I try to run it, I get the following error:
Game.Initialize() caught exception initializing XACT.
Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.NoAudioHardwareException (0x80004005): OpenAL device could not be initialized, see console output for details.
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.OpenALSoundController..ctor() in D:\GitlabRunner\builds\Gq5qA5P4\1\ConcernedApe\stardewvalley\MonoGame.Desktop\MonoGame.Framework\Platform\Audio\OpenALSoundController.cs:line 117
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.OpenALSoundController.EnsureInitialized() in D:\GitlabRunner\builds\Gq5qA5P4\1\ConcernedApe\stardewvalley\MonoGame.Desktop\MonoGame.Framework\Platform\Audio\OpenALSoundController.cs:line 300
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffect.Initialize() in D:\GitlabRunner\builds\Gq5qA5P4\1\ConcernedApe\stardewvalley\MonoGame.Desktop\MonoGame.Framework\Audio\SoundEffect.cs:line 196
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.SoundEffect..ctor(MiniFormatTag codec, Byte[] buffer, Int32 channels, Int32 sampleRate, Int32 blockAlignment, Int32 loopStart, Int32 loopLength) in D:\GitlabRunner\builds\Gq5qA5P4\1\ConcernedApe\stardewvalley\MonoGame.Desktop\MonoGame.Framework\Audio\SoundEffect.cs:line 153
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio.WaveBank..ctor(AudioEngine audioEngine, String waveBankFilename, Boolean streaming, Int32 offset, Int32 packetsize) in D:\GitlabRunner\builds\Gq5qA5P4\1\ConcernedApe\stardewvalley\MonoGame.Desktop\MonoGame.Framework\Audio\Xact\WaveBank.cs:line 276
   at StardewValley.Game1.Initialize() in D:\GitlabRunner\builds\Gq5qA5P4\1\ConcernedApe\stardewvalley\Farmer\Farmer\Game1.cs:line 2229

I'm thinking this tells me that I need a sound device, which obviously my Docker container doesn't have. Is it possible to mimic a sound device in a Docker container just enough to satiate the requirement here?

This page describes three possible ways how to set up sound for docker containers without x11docker. Most common is the easy ALSA setup. A bit more advanced, but with better integration in most desktop environments is a setup with Pulseaudio.
TLDR
Share the host’s sound devices:
docker run --rm --device /dev/snd --group-add audio your_image_name


I did see this page. The most easy setup would probably be ideal and sufficient for my needs, but I'm confused a bit on where I'd be running this. It says that x11docker provides this setup with --alsa, but I'm guessing that's just informative and what follows is for still doing it without x11docker?
